# Estimation higher order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

Consider non-dimensional differential equation for the height at the highest point is given by
\begin{equation} h(\mu)= \frac{1}{\mu}- \frac{1}{\mu^2} \log_e(1+\mu) \end{equation}
$0<\mu\ll 1.$
Deduce an estimate to $O(\mu)$ for $h(\mu)$ and compare with $t_h(\mu)=1-\frac{\mu}{2}+\cdots$

=> I really don't how to start this question. please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that $\log_e(1+\mu) = \mu - \dfrac{\mu^2}{2} + \dfrac{\mu^3}{3} - \dfrac{\mu^4}{4}+\cdots$ and plug that in, you get $\dfrac12- \dfrac\mu3+\dfrac{\mu^2}{4}+\cdots.$

Comment: Minor typo: The third term in the series for $\log$ should have $u^3$

Comment: Fixed.  (But it's not $u^3$; it's $\mu^3$.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I'll trade you a typo for a typo, it's fair I swear!

Comment: ok ${}\qquad{}$